# Stealing session id cookies - counter measures

Tags: javascript, security, session-hijacking

It is easy to steal session id cookies with javascript functions planted in trusted sites by other users. What are the possible counter-measures for this kind of attack?

Rejecting all javascript scripts on the client-side is probably difficult because almost all sites use js. What are the possible counter-measures on the server-side? Is it possible to include a hash of the client ip-address in the session id value to prevent that a valid session id be used from another host? Does this approach make sense?

In one of the resources mentioned in your valuable answers a solution is proposed where the session id is changed after every request. Is such a feature already supported by the app servers / frameworks? In particular how about Django/python?

Comment: if a malicious site gets into the Trusted Sites zone, the user is pretty hosed regardless of your site.  regardless, how exactly does a trusted site read out cookied from another domain?  if that's really possible, couldn't the malicious trusted site could make use of the hijacked session id from the client side in which case IP filtering isn't going to help

Comment: if you regenerate the session ID after every request, you break the users ability to use the back button.  the wikipedia article you mention only suggests regeneration after a successful login

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible to include a hash of
>   the client ip-address in the session
>   id value to prevent that a valid
>   session id be used from another host?
>   Does this approach make sense?

This can block session hijacking in some situation, but in situation where the attacker computer and victim computer are on the same network, it won't do anything since the connection comes from the same IP address.

> What are the possible counter-measures on the server-side ?

Using SSL will help prevent session hijacking if a person is connected to a public network.

You can review your code and make sure you have no [XSS](http://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-site_Scripting_%28XSS%29) flaw in your code.

You can also make sure the cookie used to stored the session has the [HTTP Only](http://www.owasp.org/index.php/HttpOnly) flag.

Answer (score 4):

It's really awkward to do IP to session mapping, because you don't have guarantees that people aren't using proxies, and those proxies could easily change IPs.

The best thing you can do is use SSL, and make your cookies [HTTP-only](http://www.owasp.org/index.php/HttpOnly).

Comment: @Alfred SSL helps to prevent session hijacking if you are connected to a public network.

Answer (score 2):

You'd want to specify that some cookie is for some host, domain, subdomain or whatever. Cookies support that.

I don't think that you can access cookies from other domains.

Comment: I don't think you have understood is question well, what he meant is to store the IP in session so that he can check if the session and the IP are matching.

Comment: Hey, maybe you're right, but in fact, he said that thing about IP as his suggestion to solve the problem. That's why I answered this and I've skipped the IP thing because there's nothing to do with this approach (it's not reliable).

Answer (score 1):

- Only install javascript you trust. Inspect the source code(Maybe use some sort of XSS scanner) if you are unsure about code.
- filter your javascript(from input) using for example this simple javascript snippet:

  function sanitize(html){
      `return String(html)
      .replace(/&(?!\w+;)/g, '&')
      .replace(/
      .replace(/>/g, '>')
      .replace(/"/g, '"');
  }

You **MUST** also have good filtering(input) server-side. For example PHP has [filter extension](http://php.net/manual/en/book.filter.php).

- Use [http-only cookies](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2008/08/protecting-your-cookies-httponly.html).
- Use SSL.

Comment: Will your sanitizer also work if you include an external javascript?

Comment: It depends on how you define external javascript. If you get it from json or input from user or something like that would. But a script tag(<script src='a.js'>) inside your HTML will not be safe!

Answer (score 1):

This is called [XSS](http://www.owasp.org/index.php/XSS). The best solution in to prevent the planting of JavaScript code on the clients in the first place.

<strike>An interesting solution is to provide a token-based autentication to every user operation. Check out the [OWASP CSRF page](http://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-Site_Request_Forgery_%28CSRF%29_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet) for more information.</strike>

**Edit:** As the comment says, the token won't help mitigating the session hijacking issue. As the Wikipedia article says about [Session Hijacking](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Session_hijacking#Prevention), [the best solution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Session_hijacking#Prevention) is to rotate the Session ID, possible every time the page reloads.

Comment: Token-based authentication has nothing to do with session hijacking. That won't stop it.

Comment: Do you know whether rotating the Session ID is supported "out of the box" by frameworks / app servers?